# Java Socket command system?

Tags: java, sockets, command, client-server, serversocket

I am working on a client / server application. I wrote a basic String based command system a few months back. It sends Strings to the server. The server recognizes those Strings as commands and responds correspondingly. Currently I've got about 40 different commands with different parameters.

I'm sick of formatting Strings. I want to rewrite the command system and I want to get it right this time. So far I've been using `PrintWriter`'s `println()` to send commands and `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` to receive responses.

What is the best way to write this kind of command system? So many other applications do this, but how exactly?

Comment: Design an api or restful api ? Could do it yourself in plain java or use a tool like swagger

Comment: I would like to do it myself in plain java. But I don't really know how to approach it.